# Why I am getting wrong URI?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am currently on

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/
```

I have a link that has to route me to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/create
```

I used this in my code

```
            <a
                href="cars/create"
            </a>
```

In my `web.php` I have following route

```
Route::get('cars/create',function ()
{
    return view('carsops.create');
});
```

When I click on link I am redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/cars/create
```

Instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/create
```

What is the error why I am getting this extra /cars.
Can some one help me.

Comment: Look into [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes), makes changing URLs and linking a lot easier

Comment: Have you tried : Route::get('./create',function () ... - not really sure it would work ... but since you are already in cars.... you don't need it in the new get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a `/` in front of the link:

```
        <a
            href="/cars/create"
        </a>
```

This means `Go to the site root, then got to cars path then go to the create path`.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution is not nice. Why? Ok, you should use route names in the your application.

**How to solve this problem correctly?**

A first step is set name to your route. Modify `routes/web.php` like to

```php
Route::get('cars/create',function ()
{
    return view('carsops.create');
})->name('carsops.create');
```

Look at the `name`. Name can be as you wish.

Step 2 is, calling your route in the blade like to

```php
<a
    href="{{ route('carsops.create') }}"
</a>
```

Well done.

Comment: I agree completely. You should use laravel route helper. That makes it easier to refactor later, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel a href links are made by giving name,
if you want a return view without variables you don't need to get a method

```php
Route::view('cars/create','carsops.create')->name('yournamelink');
```

use in blade page

```html
<a href="{{route('yournamelink')}}">goto page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A root-relative URL starts allway with a / character, to look something like `<a href="/cars/create">create car</a>`.

The link you posted: `<a href="cars/create">create car</a>` is linking to an folder located in a directory named create in the cars, the directory cars being in the same directory as the html page in which this link appears.

It is therefore easier to work with Laravel Helper. As already mentioned here.

```
<a href="{{ route('car.create') }}"</a>
```

You define the route names in your web.php and for api links in your api.php file.

```
Route::get('/create-car', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'create'])->name('car.create');
```